# Login users created by admin in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my application, i have admin that can create different role and user to access the admin panel, for that i am inserting a new user in the user table whose structure is :

> Users:

```
id | name | email | password | role_id
```

role id 1 and 2 is fixed for admin and normal customer respectively but after creating sub user that user cannot login because in the admin controller i have checked 1 role id for Admin but sub users have different roles also (for eg. Manager can have role id-4 and so on)

This is the Admin login controller snippet :

```
 $request->merge(["role_id" => 1]);
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,'role_id' => $request->role_id
    ], $request->input('remember_me'))) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using same **users** table for all types of users role then define user_type  as for ex- user, admin, manager, etc;
```

Login Controller code looks like

```
public function redirectTo(){
    
  $role = Auth::user()->user_type; 

    switch ($role) {
        case 'user':
                return '/user';
            break;
        case 'admin':
                return '/admin';
            break;
        default:
                return 'login'; 
            break;
    }
}

public function authenticated($request , $user){
    switch ($user->user_type){
        case 'user':
          return redirect()->route('user');
        case 'admin':
          return redirect()->route('admin');
        default:
          return redirect()->route('login') ;
    }
}
```

and middleware redirect with authenticate

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated {

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
       // return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        $role = Auth::user()->user_type; 
        switch ($role) {
            case 'user':
                    return '/user';
                break;
            case 'admin':
                    return '/admin';
                break;
            default:
                    return 'login'; 
                break;
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

**and also define route**

Comment: Thanks, Yes i' m using same user table for customer and admin but my controller for admin is different and normal user is different, but users created by admin will be able to login through admin panel, i wans checking role_id in the login controller of admin that i passed as static in request :  $request->merge(["role_id" => 1]);

Comment: Are you still getting issue?. Please let me know what is your requirement?. then i will update my answer.

Comment: route for admin and sub users (created by admin) will be same, and normal user will be different, is there any other workaround for that.

Comment: sub users do not have any limit it can be multiple,